# mysql c++ connector reduces my strings when I insert into the database

Tags: c++, mysql, string

I have a problem with mysql c++ connector when i want to insert a string with a prepared statement he reduce my string in the database(saved in a longtext) . I have enormous loss of data because I want to save a longtext.

here is my code :

```
void RequetteBDD::add(Files::Fichier file)
{

    string query = "INSERT INTO files(titre,url,type,txt,lastcrawl) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt;

    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement(query);

    prep_stmt->setString(1,file.getNom()); //title
    prep_stmt->setString(2,file.getURL().getUri()); //url
    prep_stmt->setInt(3,file.getTypeInt()); //type

    //i also try :
    istringstream stream(file.getTextFull());
    prep_stmt->setBlob(4,&stream);
    //but the saved length was exactly the same.

    prep_stmt->setString(4,file.getTextFull()); //here is the probleme

    prep_stmt->setInt(5,time(NULL)); //timstamp

    prep_stmt->execute();
    delete prep_stmt;

}
```

mysql ddb:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `titre` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT ,
  `txt` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastcrawl` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post a definition of the table in question?

Comment: The last 'setInt' - should it be 'setInt(5' instead of 'setInt(6' ?

Comment: the structure of the table is now posted

Comment: What is the length of the data before and after it is truncated?

Comment: For the page lucas.zientek.fr i have 9461 before and 8361 after and on  this page:[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W6HwKdexNY) i have 132716 and 2200 after!. Values are string.lenght(). i hope it helps you

Comment: I also try to change the txt column type but I always have the say probleme I think it comes from mysql connector c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a encoding problem; they are two solution to solve the probleme:

- change the encoding from the database to ASCII
- Or change the encoding from the string can be easely do with boost::locale::conv

I hope it will help other people.